CrashLoopBack and unable to expose Sentry-web
I finished deploying Sentry
The kafka-controller keeps going into CrashLoopBackOff.
For kafka-controller
[2024-08-29 14:39:51,534] WARN [RaftManager id=0] Error connecting to node sentry-kafka-controller-1.sentry-kafka-controller-headless.svc.cluster.local:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: sentry-kafka-controller-1.sentry-kafka-controller-headless.svc.cluster.local
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:801)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1385)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.resolveAddresses(ClusterConnectionStates.java:536)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:466)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:1050)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:310)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.sendRequests(InterBrokerSendThread.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.pollOnce(InterBrokerSendThread.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.InterBrokerSendThread.doWork(InterBrokerSendThread.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:131)

Additionally for exposing sentry-web, so I can view the UI and start testing the tool -
I made this yaml for service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sentry-web-service
  namespace: gopikab
spec:
  selector:
    app: sentry
    release: sentry
    role: web
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9000

but its still not accessible.
I reduced the no of kafka controller replicas from 3 to 1 in case it was a resource issue - but they still keep dying.

This information is not enough, add Kafka error logs too in your body question or everything may help others to understand your problem easily.
